# Parsing a CSV list from command line argument in Haskell

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments, haskell-platform

I have a program that takes some command lines arguments.

Say the first command line argument is a comma separated value (CSV) list of integers.

I want to convert the first argument `"1,2,4,8,16"` to `[1,2,4,8,16]`. I attempted to parse the the string into an `Int` list but I got a compile error.

**Haskell Code:**

```
import System.Environment
import Data.List
import Text.Regex

main = do
  args <- getArgs

  ints <- if   (length args > 1)
          then (mapM read (splitRegex (mkRegex ",") (args!!1)))
          else [1,3,5] -- defaults
  print (ints)
```

**Compile Error:**

```
myProg.hs:10:16:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO' with actual type `[]'
    In the expression: [1, 3, 5]
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      ints <- if (length args > 1) then
                  (mapM read (splitRegex (mkRegex ",") (args !! 1)))
              else
                  [1, 3, 5]
    In the expression:
      do { args <- getArgs;
           ints <- if (length args > 1) then
                       (mapM read (splitRegex (mkRegex ",") (args !! 1)))
                   else
                       [1, ....];
           print (ints) }
```

I am unsure what this type error means. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain the type error to me and how to modify my code to achieve the desired result.

Comment: I'd suggest using cassava to parse CSV rather than regex. Not an answer to your question I know but probably the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to use `<-` to define `ints` because you're not executing an IO action in there.  You can just use a `let` binding.  That also lets you replace the call to `mapM` with a plain `map`.

The first proper argument is also indexed at 0, rather than 1 like you might see in C.  You can use `head` to get at that as well.

```
let ints = if   length args >= 1
           then map read (splitRegex (mkRegex ",") (head args))
           else [1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
if   (length args > 1)
then (mapM read (splitRegex (mkRegex ",") (args!!1)))
else [1,3,5] -- defaults
```

is ill typed because the values for the two cases (then, else) do not coincide. The type of mapM is

```
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
```

so the then branch is of type m [b] for some monad m (in this case, IO). The else branch, however, is just a list of numbers. You can fix the error by writing

```
return [1,3,5]
```

for the else case, so that its type is IO [Int].

But this is probably not the best way forward. There is a problem with your then branch; the function read does not return a value in IO, so it's not suitable as the first argument to mapM here. Indeed, there's no reason to do this computation in IO, since the value of ints is obtained as a pure function of the arguments (args). I recommend implementing it outside of main, as a function with type

```
extractInts :: [String] -> [Int]
```

You can then work it into main like so:

```
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  let ints = extractInts args
  print ints
```